Call a static method of interface defined in java caused NoClassDefFoundError error after compiled with groovy
Have a static method of interface in java (from Orekit):
public interface DataContext {
    @DefaultDataContext
    static LazyLoadedDataContext getDefault() {
        return DefaultDataContextHolder.getInstance();
    }
}

and when I call DataContext.getDefault() in a groovy project, everything works well.
But after I build the project to a jar, and use it in another project, the NoClassDefFoundError is thrown.
I found this in the decompile jar file:
DataProvidersManager manager = ((Class)((Class)DataContext.class.invoke<invokedynamic>(DataContext.class)).invoke<invokedynamic>(DataContext.class.invoke<invokedynamic>(DataContext.class))).cast<invokedynamic>(((Class)DataContext.class.invoke<invokedynamic>(DataContext.class)).invoke<invokedynamic>(DataContext.class.invoke<invokedynamic>(DataContext.class)));

It seems that groovy treat the interface as class.
How to resolve this? Is there some compiler config option to elimate the cast?

If the no-class-found is about DataContext, are you sure it's actually there in your classpath/jar?

@cfrick You are right. After add the orekit as dependency of the new project, or extract orekit to the compiled jar, everything works.
